# Inserting HTML into Razor view based on conditional value

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, conditional-operator

```
 @(item.ID == 0 ? "" : <i class="fas fa-bus"></i>)
```

When I try the above statement, Razor doesn't like it, It looks like valid C# code.
What do I need to do to wrap my html tags so that it will be rendered in my UI if the ID is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@if (item.ID == 0)
{
    @:<i class="fas fa-bus"></i>
}
```

In razor pages, anything that follows the `@:` will be treated as content block.

Answer (score 0):

Try to  use :

```
@if (item.ID != 0)
{
    <i class='fas fa-bus'></i>
}
```